# How to set 100% opacity of this element?

Tags: html, css, opacity

I am beginner in Web Development and I'm creating my first site. I want to set the visible of class .maintitle (with text Jakub Poznanski) on 100% every time, but it's coliding with hover options for a list when opacity is set on 0.6. Anyone know how to fix this issue? Code and github link under. + If you have any advices for me i am open

**GitHub link:** https://github.com/Vorhacz/HTML-CSS/tree/main/websiteCV

```css
* {
  transition: 300ms;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.logo-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

.underlogotext {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script';
  font-size: 19px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(images/background.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px, 10%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.maintitle a {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #bed6ff;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #e5eafc;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #bed6ff;
}

nav ul li a:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="maintitle"><a href="#">Jakub Poznański</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">O mnie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Umiejętności</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Doświadczenie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png">
      <p class="underlogotext">Tutaj będzie jakiś mądry opis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why set opacity to `0.6` under `nav ul li a:not(:hover)` if that isn't what you want? It may be helpful to make more restrictive selectors by adding your own classes to the code. For now, a "hackish" solution that solves the immediate problem would be `nav ul li:not(.maintitle) a:not(:hover)` as a selector instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  transition: 300ms;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.logo-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

.underlogotext {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script';
  font-size: 19px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(images/background.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px, 10%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.maintitle a {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #bed6ff;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #e5eafc;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #bed6ff;
}

nav ul li a {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="maintitle"><a href="#">Jakub Poznański</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">O mnie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Umiejętności</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Doświadczenie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png">
      <p class="underlogotext">Tutaj będzie jakiś mądry opis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think you should change two of your last css styles like in my modifications of your example.

On the moderator's demand just a little explanation on the issue.

The “a” element that comprises “Jakub Poznanski” text has got under influence of two css rules simultaneously - with a selector  “.maintitle a” and “nav ul li a:not(:hover)”. With the first rule  1-point  opacity was applied to the a-element with Jakub Poznanski text, at the same time with the second one opacity of the a-element with the text was reset to 0.6 this way discarding initial opacity setting of the first rule.  So my changes of the last two css rules corrected the situation.

Comment: hi, please could you provide further explanation for future readers so they know how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

By taking a look at your code on Github I noticed that you set the opacity for every hyperlink `<a>` element to 0.6 opacity. There are a few things you can do to fix the issue, but I think the solution I give you below is the best.

Using opacity to change colors is actually not the best idea, because your elements will also become transparent. Looking at the website you have build until now I would recommend changing it to actual colors instead. This will always keep the colors consistent no matter what background color you use. So you're CSS code will become something like this.

```
nav ul li a { color: #898d98 }

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li.maintitle a { color: #bed6ff }
```

This way your `.maintitle` hyperlink element will always have the same color.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Change to `nav ul li:not(.maintitle) a:not(:hover)`:

```css
* {
  transition: 300ms;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.logo-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

.underlogotext {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script';
  font-size: 19px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(images/background.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px, 10%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.maintitle a {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #bed6ff;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #e5eafc;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #bed6ff;
}

nav ul li:not(.maintitle) a:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="maintitle"><a href="#">Jakub Poznański</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">O mnie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Umiejętności</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Doświadczenie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png">
      <p class="underlogotext">Tutaj będzie jakiś mądry opis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```